# PUT #update controller test fails as it does not modify given object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test my update action in rails api with rspec, however test suite I wrote seems to not update object with params provided.

In my api I have two models: Clan and Samurai, where Samurai belongs to Clan and Clan has many Samurais. 
I use factory bot to generate fixtures and Clan fixture is defined in outer scope (hence clan.id).

```
# ../samurais_controller_spec.rb

describe "PUT #update" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      let(:new_attributes) { { name: "Danny Boy" } }
      let(:new_samurai) { create(:samurai, name: "Danny", clan_id: clan.id) }

      it "updates samurai" do
        put :update, params: { clan_id: new_samurai.clan_id,
                               id:      new_samurai.id,
                               samurai: new_attributes }
        new_samurai.reload
        expect(new_samurai.name).to eq(new_attributes[:name])
      end
    end
  end
```

```
# ../samurais_controller.rb

def update
      samurai.update!(samurai_params)

      render json: samurai.to_json
end

...

private

    def clan
      @clan ||= Clan.find(params[:clan_id])
    end

    def samurai
      @samurai ||= Samurai.find_by!(id: params[:id], clan_id: params[:clan_id])
    end

    def samurai_params
      params.permit(:name, :death_date, :armor_quality, :number_of_battles, :join_date)
    end
```

Whenever I run rspec I receive this error:

```
1) Clans::SamuraisController PUT #update with valid attributes updates samurai
     Failure/Error: expect(new_samurai.name).to eq(new_attributes[:name])

       expected: "Danny Boy"
            got: "Danny"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/samurais_controller_spec.rb:84:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
```

which confuses me a bit since when I run `samurai.update! some_params` in console it works fine.

I believe the problem lies in test suite somehow not updating the correct samurai, so I tried stubbing it with:

```
before(:each) do
     Samurai.should_receieve(:find).and_return(new_samurai)
end
```

but it didn't work (and is deprecated).

I'd be glad for help.

Update:

```
# ../schema.rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_03_14_150921) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "clans", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "samurais", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.integer "armor_quality", default: 0
    t.integer "number_of_battles", default: 0
    t.date "join_date"
    t.date "death_date"
    t.bigint "clan_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["clan_id"], name: "index_samurais_on_clan_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "samurais", "clans"
end
```

Comment: Could you please add what the Samurai schema is and what `samurai_params` is in `# ../samurais_controller.rb`?

Comment: Can you please make sure that your `update` method was executed (put `binding.pry` and run the test)? If you manage to do this, please check what is returned by `samurai_params`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `samurai_params` method in your controller to:

```
def samurai_params
  params.require(:samurai).permit(:name, :death_date, :armor_quality, :number_of_battles, :join_date)
end
```

Or modify your spec to send new attributes directly (without nesting them in a hash):

```
request_params = { clan_id: new_samurai.clan_id, id: new_samurai.id }
request_params.merge!(new_attributes)
put :update, params: request_params
```

Comment: Yes, it works now, thanks! I realised that alternatively I can just provide :name key to param hash (without :samurai), but I believe this is not preferable.

Comment: In my opinion, it is better to wrap params with `:samuarai` key.